# No main class in manifest and it's read only

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm searching for solution for two days now and nothing works. First of all I'm using Intellij 2018.3, and when I open project folder main manifest is read only, and there is no option on right click or file... to make it writable. There is no Main class. Options build path and so are not working... I'm going crazy. Did anyone had the same problem?

p.s. there is no .settings also. And in jar file is just classes

Comment: When is this "no main class" message appearing? When building the project?

Comment: When I run the app I get "no main manifest attribute" error

Comment: wkt is cause I'm new in this and don't know if it is possible to run without main class.

Comment: Please provide screenshots describing the problem. What is read-only manifest has to do with the "no main manifest attribute" error when you run the app? How do you run it? Please check also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html#package

Comment: I wanted to insert Main-class in manifest, but I can't cause it's read-only.

Comment: do you have the java source files so you are  able to build a new jar or did you just start from an existing jar ?

Comment: I started from the existing jar, I don't have source files. I'm newbie as you may noticed, but I'm confused about project structure. There is no bin, lib, main class... I have manage everything but main manifest attribute issue